# Issue with removing new lines & printf

Tags: c, windows, printf, mingw, newline

A txt file is read in binary mode and stored in a buffer (I'm writing a HEX editor so it's important that files are read in binary mode):

[image: original file]

The following code removes any new lines and prints the txt to the console:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

FILE *fileptr;
unsigned char *buffer;
long filelen;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    fileptr = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    fseek(fileptr, 0, SEEK_END);
    filelen = ftell(fileptr);
    rewind(fileptr);

    buffer = (char *)malloc((filelen+1)*sizeof(char));
    fread(buffer, filelen, 1, fileptr);
    fclose(fileptr); // Close the file

    for (int i = 0; i < filelen; i++){
        if (buffer[i] == '\n'){
            printf(".");
        }else{
            printf("%c", buffer[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the **intended** output, **what we want**:
[image: expected output]

This is the **actual** output, **not what we want**:
[image: incorrect/actual output]

When a `sleep();` command is added this is what seems to be occurring(*Second line highlighted in green for clarity*):

[image]

The first line prints fine, then the new line is reached, this is where the error is occurring the new line seems to be removed, only **the cursor jumps back to the beginning of the line**, this behavior is not expected nor is it wanted.

Comment: How do you open the file? Text or binary mode?

Comment: Please post real and complete code. Typing some random text from memory is error prone, while copy&paste is not. You mess up your index variables in the loop. Please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Linux and Windows have different ways to terminate lines in text files. When using Mingw this becomes confusing as you have to decide which standard to follow. Are you running Linux or Windows, and which system does the text file belong to?

Comment: @BoPersson Looking at the directory names it must be Windows.

Comment: The canonical text file format on Windows has each line terminated by two ASCII characters: CR followed by LF. In C on Windows, these character codes should map to the `\r` and `\n` escape codes respectively. When written to the console, CR moves the cursor to the first column, and LF moves the cursor down one line in the same column. Your animation shows the cursor being moved to the first column due to the CR character. I suggest replacing both `\n` and `\r` with a `.` in your code. The output will then show two dots at the end of each of the original text lines.

Comment: This can become an issue with other characters too e.g. `'\t'`. May be, it is a better idea to use `printf("%c", buffer[i] >= ' ' && buffer[i] < 127 ? buffer[i] : '.');`. Btw. you mixed `i` and `a` as loop index. (Already complained by Gerhardh.)

Comment: Hey thanks guys! I've added everything that was mentioned.

Comment: Solved!! Thanks everyone for the help!! Very much appreciated!!

Comment: Change `if (buffer[i] == '\n')` to `if (!isprint((unsigned char) buffer[i]))` to handle _all_ "unprintable" characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
for (int i = 0; i < len; a++){
    if ((buffer[i] == 10) || (buffer[i]==13)){
        printf(".");
    }else{
        printf("%c", buffer[a]);
    }
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

as you know unix, dos and mac `.txt` files have different ways of indicating the start of a new line and this could be causing an issue for you - In the revised code instead of looking for `\n` the program looks for ascii codes 10 and 13 - line feed and carriage return. The one undesirable consequence is that you will get two `.`s between lines for ms-dos type files, but you could modify around that provided you **knew** you would only ever have ms-dos type `.txt` files

The other thing I have added that may or may not be necessary is `fflush(stdout);` because often when you `printf` things do not appear immediately on the screen and this should force things to be printed. It may not be necessary.

I think the reason that you get one line written on top of the other is because you have a dos type `.txt` file with a carriage return and a linefeed character at the end of each line - you are catching the linefeed with your `\n` `if` statement, but not the carriage return which sends the cursor to the beginning of the line and means that the first part of the text file is overwritten by the second part.

Comment: Thanks @tom, your solution worked brilliantly, thanks for explaining it so well too!! you're an absolute legend!!

Comment: @GCaldL- glad that this was useful, all best wishes